# clear (the text) and edit all .json files in a folder

Tags: editing

I have a folder with a lot of .json file. I would like to replace the contents of these files by something in particular. I can erase all the text of all json files:

```
FOR /R C:\YourFolder %%f IN (*.json) DO TYPE NUL>%%f
```

I can write to a .json file in particular:

```
@echo off


(echo {) > NAME.json
(echo  "parent": "minecraft:recipes/root",) >> NAME.json
(echo   "rewards": {) >> NAME.json
(echo     "recipes": [) >> NAME.json
(echo       "minecraft:stone") >> NAME.json
(echo     ]) >> NAME.json
(echo   },) >> NAME.json
(echo   "criteria": {) >> NAME.json
(echo     "impossible": {) >> NAME.json
(echo       "trigger": "minecraft:impossible") >> NAME.json
(echo     }) >> NAME.json
(echo   },) >> NAME.json
(echo     "has_the_recipe": {) >> NAME.json
(echo       "trigger": "minecraft:recipe_unlocked",) >> NAME.json
(echo       "conditions": {) >> NAME.json
(echo         "recipe": "minecraft:stone") >> NAME.json
(echo       }) >> NAME.json
(echo     }) >> NAME.json
(echo   },) >> NAME.json
(echo   "requirements": [) >> NAME.json
(echo     [) >> NAME.json
(echo       "impossible") >> NAME.json
(echo     ]) >> NAME.json
(echo   ]) >> NAME.json
(echo }) >> NAME.json
exit
```

But I can not combine the two

sorry if it's not very clear, I'm not english :)